# Application service parameters / return types

Tags: domain-driven-design

I work on standard web application with domain organized around DDD concepts. I'm wondering what kind of objects my application services should accept and return. Let's say that I have an application service for `User` aggregate.

**1) DTOs / simple types (string, int etc)**

```
public interface UserApplicationService {
  void registerUser(UserDTO userDTO);
  List<UserDTO> getUsersForOrganization(String organizationId);
}
```

In this case, application service is responsible for calling assembler transforming DTOs to domain objects and the other way round.

Advantage of this approach is that my application service is a clear boundary for my domain objects. Another one is that application service is a clear transaction boundary. Domain objects that are managed by persistence context do not leak somewhere outside of the transaction.

Disadvantage is that in case of forms, validation must be based on DTO. So my validation rules are duplicated between domain (object is responsible for its state) and DTO validation rules. (As in case of [Spring MVC sample application](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/form/FormBean.java)). Also, if some parts of view requires another form of model (let's say that UserDTO has not enough information for view to be rendered), I'll need to create another DTO and basis on couple of DTOs returned from application service, compose another one, used by view.

**2) Domain types**

```
public interface UserApplicationService {
  void registerUser(User user);
  List<User> getUsersForOrganization(OrganizationId organizationId);
}
```

In this case, controller / presenter is responsible for transformation.

Big disadvantage is that my domain objects leak from application service - no clear separation. Also, where are our transaction boundaries? Domain objects that may be attached to, for example Hibernate session, leaks outside of application services layer. (However, I noticed that this is how many sample applications are written.)

Advantage may be that the controller / presenter is responsible for preparation of model for view, so it can compose DTOs basis on the view requirements. For instance, view may require some additional information that is not returned in DTO from #getUsersForOrganizationMethod. Also, validation may be based on domain objects, so it's not duplicated between DTOs and domain objects.

**3) Domain objects + facade**

This is third option used in [DDDsample application](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/download.html). Application services return domain types, but there is some facade that is responsible for transformation. So in my case, controller / presenter talks to facade with DTOs, facade does the transformation and it talks with application services using domain objects. However, in my humble opinion it seems a little bit overwhelming - too many layers, too many boilerplate code. For one application service it may sound great, but if we had tens of them, we need to have the same number of facade methods - pure duplication. Additionally, where are transaction boundaries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

+1

I prefer a mixed solution.

1) I use domain objects as arguments, but limited to **ValueObject** s. I believe the lifecycle of **Entity** s should be managed carefully, and most of the time the view doesn't have enough value to populate the whole **Entity** except very simple CRUD applications. I saw many times that some developers init **Entity** by constructor carelessly and populate them with only part of the fields they required for a particular function, this makes it very easy to introduce bugs for NullPointerException and the poor guy who is assigned to fix the issue has to search across tens of methods to find where the **Entity** given was created. **Entity** s are retrieved from **Repository** or created by **Factory** in my projects.

Sometimes I use some form objects as parameter for simplicity.

2) I use a mvc Controller to convert domain objects returned by application service to ViewAdapter(a componenet decouples domain models from ui), sometimes dettach work need to be done here.

3) I use a **Facade** only when the application service need to be exposed via remote procedure call like web-service. **Dto** s are used as arguments and return types in this case and the **Facade** is responsible for converting **DTO** and **Domain Model**.

4) Validation is awkward if the application service need to be exposed to both web view and remote procedure call. This causes duplicate validation implemented on both form objects and Dtos. I validate simple constraints only(Not null, length to name a few, business rules are validated by domain objects programmatically) because I haven't found a perfect solution yet.

Hope this helps and if there are better solutions do let me know please.

**Update1：**

1) I have to confess that I'm not a guru in this area and I'm trying to find a good solution as well. So sometimes there is some inconsistency in my current solution such as the form bean you mentioned in comment. Sometimes we take some form bean as Command and place some domain logic in it, so these command belong to Domain Layer in this case.

2) Transaction boundary is on the application service. Technically, The domain object could be modified out of the boundary inadvertently. We cover this by team discipline and code review.

Comment: Nice answer,thanks! Couple of comments: 1) if you accept VO in application services, what would be your parameter type in case of operation such as checkout? There are couple of products you'd like to pass in one method invocation and you'll need some aggregate for all of them-here comes DTOs IMHO; I think that form bean belongs to presentation layer and should not be accepted by service. 2) Where are your transaction boundaries? If we return entities from services it would allow controller to modify it and potentially lead to some weird issues (especially if entity is a transactional proxy).

Comment: @woof-woof some updates and I don't quite get the "checkout" and "products", could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Let's say that you have a shop application and user wants to buy some number of products A and products B. So user is performing a checkout (this is my understanding :)). User wants to checkout (buy) all or nothing - that's why we'll need some object to aggregate items and their quantity.

Comment: @woof-woof Just like a shopping cart? It's hard to say is this a Dto or not. Sometimes the shopping cart even need to be persisted for user review. But it does happen that some objects are just "transient" (not used later in Domain layer), this is annoying to me as well.

Answer (score 4):

I usually find myself leaning towards approach one, using commands and queries.

Here is a snippet of a blog post I'm publishing this weekend.

> Commands help you in supporting the ubiquitous language by explicitly
>   capturing user intent at the boundaries of your system - think use
>   cases. They serve as a layer over your domain, decoupling the inside
>   from the outside, allowing you to gradually introduce concepts on the
>   inside, without breaking the outside. The command executor gives you a
>   nice pipeline you can take advantage of to centralize security,
>   performance metrics, logging, session management and so on. And also,
>   if that's your thing - commands can be serialized dealt with
>   asynchronously.

You can find an example of this on my blog; http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/01/separating-command-data-from-logic-and.html.

In respect to your concerns regarding validation, keep in mind that having validation duplicated isn't horrible;  http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/05/19/validation-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/.

Answer (score 0):

I use a bit of all three of your approaches but in a very consistent way that adheres to the layering principles that Eric Evans describes in the DDD [blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

Input to application layers is always simple types (or object parameters encapsulating them), output is always domain types, and the presentation layer handles the mapping to/from view types (DTOs).

I explain my reasons for taking this approach in my answer to a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230822/509891