# Automapper performance

Tags: c#, performance, automapper

I'm using Automapper to map my business model to a ViewModel.

It works, but it's very slow.

I have a collection with 6893 objects with 23 properties (test environment, production should have much more).

With a loop it takes `00:02:32.8118534` to map everything.

```
var objects = // get all items (returns a collection of MyObj)
List<MyViewModel> collection = new List<MyViewModel>();
foreach (MyObj obj in objects)
{
     MyViewModel vm = Mapper.Map<MyObj, MyViewModel>(obj);
     collection.Add(vm);
}
```

I tried to improve it like this:

```
var objects = // get all items (returns a collection of MyObj)
IEnumerable<MyViewModel> collection = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyObj>, IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>(objects);
```

And it took `00:02:25.4527961` to map everything.

So it didn't help that much.

None of my object's properties can be `null`.

This is how I configured the mapper:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<MyObj, MyViewModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MyObjOtherObj, MyViewModelOtherObj>();
        });
mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

MyObj:

```
public partial class MyObj
{
    public MyObj()
    {
        this.MyObjOtherObj= new HashSet<MyObjOtherObj>();
    }

    public long a{ get; set; }
    public short b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    public string d{ get; set; }
    public string e{ get; set; }
    public string f{ get; set; }
    public string g{ get; set; }
    public string h{ get; set; }
    public string i{ get; set; }
    public string j{ get; set; }
    public string k{ get; set; }
    public string l{ get; set; }
    public string m{ get; set; }
    public bool n{ get; set; }
    public bool o{ get; set; }
    public bool p{ get; set; }
    public bool q{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyObjOtherObj> MyObjOtherObj{ get; set; }
    public virtual Types Types { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public long a{ get; set; }
    public short b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    public string d{ get; set; }
    public string e{ get; set; }
    public string f{ get; set; }
    public string g{ get; set; }
    public string h{ get; set; }
    public string i{ get; set; }
    public string j{ get; set; }
    public string k{ get; set; }
    public string l{ get; set; }
    public string m{ get; set; }
    public bool n{ get; set; }
    public bool o{ get; set; }
    public bool p{ get; set; }
    public bool q{ get; set; }
    public string TypesDescription { get; set; }

    public List<MyViewModelOtherObj> MyObjOtherObj { get; set; }
}
```

MyObjOtherObj:

```
public partial class MyObjOtherObj
{
    public long id{ get; set; }
    public long MyObjId { get; set; }
    public short x{ get; set; }
    public string z{ get; set; }

    public virtual MyObj MyObj{ get; set; }
    public virtual SourceTypes SourceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModelOtherObj:

```
public class MyViewModelOtherObj
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long MyObjId { get; set; }
    public short x{ get; set; }
    public string z{ get; set; }
    public string SourceTypesDescription { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

SourceTypes:

```
public partial class SourceTypes
{
    public SourceTypes()
    {
        this.MyObjOtherObj = new HashSet<MyObjOtherObj>();
    }

    public short SourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyObjOtherObj> MyObjOtherObj { get; set; }
}
```

Types:

```
public partial class Types
{
    public Types()
    {
        this.MyObj = new HashSet<MyObj>();
    }

    public short TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyObj> MyObj{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the code of both objects?

Comment: so what's your question? have you tried to look for hotspots? how are the other objects created?

Comment: Have you checked that they are fully loaded objects, i.e. it's not being slowed up by an ORM lazy loading the attached objects?

Comment: @RichLinnell Yes, the objects are fully loaded.

Comment: @DanielA.White my question is how to improve this ***** performance. I already searched about it, but since I didn't found anything, I thought that maybe the problem was with my code.

Comment: is MyObjOtherObj empty?

Comment: I would start by adjusting the mapping to ignore the collection on the model. Try it and see if that makes a dramatic difference. If so I would re enable it and start examining the effects of various things e.g. Changing the collection types, explicitly mapping the SourceTypesDescription.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: What are Types and SourceTypes? I didn't see them in the code.

Comment: @JimmyBogard see my edit, I posted the Types and SourceTypes objects. I didn't post them before because I only get their description.

Comment: @RichLinnell, you are right. I adjust the mapping to ignore the collection on the model and the whole request took 1.6s for 17803 objects. But I need the collection. Now I have to figure out how to use the collection.

Comment: @lpfx check out my gist below. I tried to make it just like your objects, but not sure what's different exactly. How do my objects (and even # of subobjects) differ?

Comment: @JimmyBogard, I check it. It looks the same. But for sure the problem is the collection of MyObjOtherObj in MyObj. Without it, there is no performance problem. Any suggestions about collections?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that those elements in the collections on the model are all fully hydrated from the DB before mapping?  Try iterating through all of them and dumping some of their properties out to the console or wherever before doing the mapping. Does this speed up the mapping process? If they're being lazy-loaded then by iterating through outside of the mapping and "touching" them they'll be loaded.

Comment: @RichLinnell you are right once again. After iterating through all of them, the mapper configuration setup took 4s and the mapping took 7s. Is not great but is better than over 2min. Can you help me fix that? I get the objects from the DB like this: `List<MyObj> myObjs = dbContext.MyObj.ToList();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to our comments, you need to Eager load your collection objects.  Take a look at the following article this should solve your issue :

[Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so mush! I didn't know about that. I change it to `List<MyObj> myObjs = dbContext.MyObj.Include("MyObjOtherObj").ToList();` and now the whole request takes 13s (17803 objects). It is not perfect, but acceptable.

Answer (score 19):

The 5.0 version of AutoMapper has significant performance increases. In our benchmarks, using a very similar type that you've shown here, we can map one million items in a little over a second. In the upcoming 5.1 version, that shrinks even more that we're only about 3x slower than hand-mapping, mainly due to null checking that hand mapping won't do.

I'd upgrade.

Comment: I'm using the last version (5.0.2)

Comment: Well then I'm really stumped, I just ran your exact object structure in our benchmarks, and mapped 1M items in 1.97 seconds. Here's my benchmark: https://gist.github.com/jbogard/faff8ad3f0a179618a9033781d8f4152

Comment: I should add this against 5.1 alpha, we added a wee bit more perf to it.

Comment: I check your gist and is almost the same. Not sure about the difference. Could the problem be the virtual properties on the objetcs Types and SourceTypes? Both are objects created by entity framework. Types has a virtual property that is a collection of MyObj. And SourceTypes a virtual property that is a collection of MyObjOtherObj. Not sure how AutoMapper works. But could this be a cyclic reference somehow that interferes with AutoMapper?

Comment: No... Could the problem be the virtual property on the object MyObjOtherObj? It is also an object created by entity framework and has a virtual property that is MyObj.

Comment: What does your SQL profiler look like? Are you getting a SELECT N+1 going on?