# Select and grouping based on different fields/integer

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Table in SQL:

```
 Document            Revision             Version
 -----------------------------------------------------
   ABC                  1                    1
   ABC                  1                    2
   ABC                  1                    8
   ABC                  2                    3
   DocumentF            1                    3
   DocumentF            1                    2
```

Expected output:

```
 Document            Revision             Version
 -----------------------------------------------------
   ABC                     1                    8
   ABC                     2                    3
   DocumentF               1                    3
```

Basically if there are two versions of the same revision, bring back the latest based on version.

I've tried the following:

```
var list = from document in documents
           group document by document.Document
           into groups
           from g in groups
           group g by g.Revision
           into final
           select final.OrderByDescending(d => d.Version).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above code produces the following:

```
 Document            Revision             Version
 -----------------------------------------------------
   ABC                     2                    3
   DocumentF               1                    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq , we can group by multiple properties like below

```
 var list = from document in documents
                       group document by (document.Document, document.Revision)
                      into groups
                       select groups.OrderByDescending(d => d.Version).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GroupBy` [multiple columns](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/40755567/group-by-multiple-column-in-linq-in-csharp), something like this:

```
 var result = documents.GroupBy(c => new { c.Document, c.Revision })
        .Select(c => new DocumentClass
        {
            Document = c.Key.Document,
            Revision = c.Key.Revision,
            Version = c.Max(d=>d.Version)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Works great - is there a way to return the whole object instead of an anonymous type? Example. my list is List<Document> documents. Document class contains: Reference (which is ABC, DocumentF), Revision, Version, and a whole bunch of fields.

Comment: @LuxC See my updated answer, all you need is just adding your class name to the `Select` part.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, is there a way to return the original object and not a new class?

Comment: @LuxC You can and it's possible with a similar way, but it has not been recommended, you should always return a DTO class, See this post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554977/should-services-always-return-dtos-or-can-they-also-return-domain-models