# clean architecture boundaries - can web layer access domain layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clean-architecture

Currently, i develop a new Microservice using clean architecture, as i understand the API layer can only access the Infrastructure layer, so i just referenced the Infrastructure on the API layer but i was noticed that the API layer can use the Entities and Exceptions that declared inside Domain layer
How can this happen? , Could someone explain this?

[Clean architecture Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GA7i.png)

I followed with different resources but there's nothing help me with that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315655/16563198 help? The short answer is that the domain layer is at the centre of the "onion", so all the other layers around it are allowed to reference it, even if they're not right next to it. As long as you don't have a layer trying to reference another layer which is further away from the centre of the "onion" than it is, then you're probably doing OK.